# Database - getting multi dimensional data

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, database, nosql

Is there some command in mysql or nosql databases so i could get data sorted in multidimensional array by some sort field?

For example : SELECT * FROM TABLE ARRAYSORT field1
so we would get

```
array('field1_value1'=>array(data),'field1_value2'=>array(data))
```

or we must process data in our programming language to get array like this.
It is just imposible that no database support query like this.

Comment: Why not add an additional table with all of your array and additional column with running numbers to maintain the order you desire?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you want to do:
PHP:

```
$result = $polaczenie->query($sql)
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
$array[$Row['firstColumnToSort']][$Row['secondColumnToSort']]=data;
}
```

Or something like that

Comment: yes, but my question was, is there built in function in any sql to return mutli dimensional array